# Not able to change Size Class Using Matrix in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have just created a new project in `XCode8` and I want to design screens in `Any|Any` Size Class.

But Not able to See any Size Matrix, Refer below screen Shot.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to know how to change it because I can see

`View as:iPhone 6s(wC hR)` size class.

Or is there any thing new in `Size Classes` in `XCode8`?

Answer (score 1):

Click 'Vary for Traits' on the right. Then, select the device and orientation where you want to add constraints to and click the 'Vary for Traits' button. Set constraints for the condition you've selected and then press 'Done Varying'.

Comment: thankyou so much for your response. The Answer you have mentioned i already checked. Would be better if you explain in detail. Like How to change size class? As you could se in screen shot CwRh is current matrix suppose i want to design AnywAnyh so can i use this. and if this type of metric feature is not available in Xcode 8 then would be better if you explain the procedure in detail. Thanks once again :)